# Does field expansion feature on facebook graph api count as using less cpu vs not using it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently we got some rate restrictions warnings on our facebook application, so I'm trying to optimize the api calls. The call I'm more concerned about is "gr:get:Post 337%" related to "Calls Are Too CPU Intensive". Unfortunately due to this bug on facebook (#151246715012616) we are forced to retrieve posts we got from a previous feed api call given the updated time is incorrect and there's not much we can do to prevent calling it until this bug is solved.

What I'm trying to figure out is if calling the getPost API with the fields parameter specifying which fields we need from it would be considered less CPU intensive than calling it without the fields restriction. The examples would be:

http://graph.facebook.com/?259479457407_10150913810457408?fields=id,updated_time,...

vs

http://graph.facebook.com/?259479457407_10150913810457408

Thanks and I would really appreciate anyone with a similar problem sharing their experience

Answer (score 0):

After switching to retrieving required fields only many of the API warnings were gone, so I'd say it count's as less cpu intensive on facebook side.